# Are trigraphs still valid C++?

Tags: c++, c++14, digraphs, trigraphs, c++17

We all know about the [historical curiosity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1234618/560648) that is [digraphs and trigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs), but with all the changes made to C++ in recent years I'm curious: are they valid C++14? How about C++17?

Comment: I'm afraid they're still valid constructs.

Comment: historical curiosity is that we still use this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typewriter#mediaviewer/File:1920s_Underwood_SE_layout.JPG

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Trigraphs are currently valid, but won't be for long!

> Trigraphs were proposed for deprecation in C++0x, which was released
>   as C++11. This was opposed by IBM, speaking on behalf of itself and
>   other users of C++, and as a result trigraphs were retained in
>   C++0x. Trigraphs were then proposed again for removal (not only
>   deprecation) in C++17. This passed a committee vote, and **trigraphs
>   are expected to be removed from C++17** despite the opposition from IBM
>   and others. Existing code that uses trigraphs can be supported by
>   translating from the physical source files (parsing trigraphs) to the
>   basic source character set that does not include trigraphs. *[[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#Removal_of_trigraphs)*

Digraphs, however, [are sticking around for now](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27601706/560648).

Comment: The [current C++17 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) is probably a better reference. (in particular, `C.4.1[diff.cpp14.lex]`)

Comment: And there was much rejoicing.