# Why can int _$[:>=<%-!.0,}; compile?

Tags: c, syntax

Today I found strange syntax like

```
 int _$[:>=<%-!.0,};
```

in some old code, but in fact the code is not commented. There seems to be no report of compile errors for this line. I tested it separately and it can compile too:

```
int main(){
    int _$[:>=<%-!.0,};
    return 0;
}
```

Why can it compile?

Comment: [What is this smiley-with-beard expression](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15736282/995714) http://stackoverflow.com/q/27678297/995714 http://stackoverflow.com/q/27601706/995714

Comment: This isn't C (because no C token can contain a dollar sign). Any compiler accepting this code translates some **other** language than C.

Comment: @Jens don't *all* compilers translate to **some other** language than C?.. Pedants aside, if you see my answer, [gnu `gcc` actually supports `$` in identifiers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html). And, as far as I can tell, so does `llvm`. I think you're confusing *machines* with compilers as some *machines* don't support $ in identifiers.

Comment: @dcow C compilers accept C as the **source** language. I'm not confusing anything. Apparantly you think that gcc is a C compiler. It is not. It accepts a language called GNU C in which `$` is acceptable in identifiers. In Standard C this is a syntax error that **must** be diagnosed. To turn gcc into a C compiler, you need to provide a set of esoteric options like `-ansi -pedantic -Wno-trigraph` or so and even then it might accept some non-C programs. C is defined by ISO9899, not by the language accepted by some random compiler.

Comment: @dcow Jens said "translates some other language", not "translates **to** some other language". A C compiler translates C (to assembly or whatever), a Java compiler translates Java (to bytecode), an assembler translates assembly (to machine code).

Comment: Is there a purpose to this line of code other than to confuse the reader and the compiler?  Who would ever jam these random symbols together unless this is from some obfuscated C contest?

Comment: Anytime C and weird symbols are involved check if there are #define for any of those weird symbols

Comment: Digraphs get asked about literally every day on stackoverflow.  I don't understand why so many copies of the same question make it to the hot questions lists... or why they aren't closed as duplicates.

Comment: @Jens sorry the distinction I was trying to make clear is not whether GNU C is ANSI C, but rather than it doesn't matter which C the compiler translates, the symbols just have to be consumable by either the underlying runtime library or, if that does no translation, the assembler.

Comment: How to get a lot of upvotes on SO: 1. Write some funky C code with digraphs. 2. Post question about it 3. PROFIT!!!

Comment: I can think of several people I've known who would write code like this. Note: I specifically *did not say* "friends" or "respected colleages"...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

With **Digraph** (see below), the line is converted to:

```
int _$[]={-!.0,};
```

On the right hand side, `.0` is the `double` literal, `!` is the logical negation operator, `-` is the arithmetic negation operator, and `,` is the trailing comma. Together `{-!.0,}` is an array initializer.

The left hand side `int _$[]` defines an `int` array. However, there's one last problem, `_$` is not a valid identifier in standard C. Some compilers (e.g, [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html)) supports it as extension.

---

> #### C11 §6.4.6 Punctuators
>
> In all aspects of the language, the six tokens
>
> ```
> <: :> <% %> %: %:%:
> ```
>
> behave, respectively, the same as the six tokens
>
> ```
> [  ]  {  }  #  ##
> ```

Comment: What options did you give gcc? With gcc-4.8 with `-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra` doesn't even give a warning. If I replace -std=c11 with -std=c89, then it warns on the $ and rejects the digraph.

Comment: @rici You are right, gcc compiles it fine, I'll edit the post. When I try it, I mistakenly thought there was no `int` (as many obfuscated code would do), so I use `-std=c89` to make sure implicit int was enabled, and gcc gives error on undeclared `_$`.

Comment: Identifiers containing `$` are apparently common in VMS.

Comment: Could you also throw in a `~` (bitwise negation) with the other unary operators?

Answer (score 38):

Well,

- underscore `_` is an allowed identifier character,
- dollar sign [`$` is allowed in some implementations too](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html),
- left bracket `[` denotes the type should be array,
- `:>` is the digraph for `]`,
- equals `=` is assignment,
- `<%` is the digraph for `{`,
- `-!.0` is just -1 (`.0` is a double literal `0.0`, `!` implicitly casts to `(int) 0` and logically inverts it, and `-` is negative),
- you can have trailing commas in array initializers {1, (2, 3,)},
- and `;` ends the statement.,

So you get

```
int _$[] = {-1,};
```

Answer (score 12):

If we replace the digraphs `:>` and `<%` present in your line of code, we end up with

```
int _$[]={-!.0,};
```

which is equivalent to

```
int _$[] = { -1, };
```

It is a declaration of array `_$` of type `int [1]` with an initializer.

Note that this is not exactly guaranteed to compile since standard C language does not immediately provide support for `$` character in indentifiers. It allows implementations to extend the set of supported charaters though. Apparently the compiler you used supported `$` in identifiers.

Answer (score 11):

This works due to [digraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) in C. The line in question decodes like this:

```
int _$ [ :> = <% - ! .0  , } ;
int _$ [ ]  = {  - ! 0.0 , } ;
```

Furthermore:

- `.0` is a `double` literal.
- `!` is the Boolean negation operator, so `!.0` yields `(int) 1`.
- `-` is the unary negation operator, which yields `(int) -1`.
- A trailing comma is legal after an array element.