# C strange macro syntax

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor-directive

I found this C code example, and I am absolutely puzzled:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M(a,b) a%:%:b

main()
{
  int a=1, b=2, ab[]={10,20}, c;
  printf( "%d", M(a,b)<:a:> );
  printf( "%d", M(a,b)<:a:>?a:b );
  printf( "%d", c=M(a,b)<:a:>?a:b );
}
```

Could someone explain what this is supposed to do? It doesn't even compile in Visual Studio, but I ran it online (on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com)) and it printed `2011`, which also added to the confusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the C ??!??! operator do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825055/what-does-the-c-operator-do)

Comment: Is this from the obfuscated C contest?

Comment: can't explain, also haven't seen before. It compiles in osx/darwin/unix. FYI, first line evaluates and prints `20`, second line `1`, third line `1`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can int _$[:>=<%-!.0,}; compile?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32001620/11683)

Comment: @GSerg: these are **digraphs** not **trigraphs**. Although they are related, it's not really a dup I reckon.

Comment: @dreamlax Digraphs were [also mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7825078/11683) so I thought it would do.

Comment: *"Digraphs get asked about literally every day on stackoverflow. I don't understand why so many copies of the same question make it to the hot questions lists... or why they aren't closed as duplicates."* – [BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft](http://stackoverflow.com/users/238419/blueraja-danny-pflughoeft), [Aug 14 '15 at 16:27](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001620/why-can-int-0-compile?lq=1#comment51931613_32001620)

Comment: @GSerg Questions with a lot of various obfuscation merged into one goo are pretty bad for duplicates. Rather, close that one as a duplicate to this.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's making use of [C digraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) which were amendments to the C standard in 1994 and therefore part of the C99 standard. Swapping the digraphs out with their actual characters, you get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M(a,b) a##b

main()
{
  int a=1, b=2, ab[]={10,20}, c;
  printf( "%d", M(a,b)[a] );
  printf( "%d", M(a,b)[a]?a:b );
  printf( "%d", c=M(a,b)[a]?a:b );
}
```

So, keep in mind that `a##b` will merge together the input into a single identifier. Since the macro is just passed `a` and `b`, the result is just `ab`, so you effectively have:

```
main()
{
  int a=1, b=2, ab[]={10,20}, c;
  printf( "%d", ab[a] );
  printf( "%d", ab[a]?a:b );
  printf( "%d", c=ab[a]?a:b );
}
```

The assignment to `c` is not really relevant, so we can get rid of that:

```
main()
{
  int a=1, b=2, ab[]={10,20};
  printf( "%d", ab[a] );
  printf( "%d", ab[a]?a:b );
  printf( "%d", ab[a]?a:b );
}
```

Now, let's get rid of the ternary operator (`?:`), because we can work it out statically (`ab[a]` is always true because `a` is 1 and `ab[1]` is 20, i.e. non-zero):

```
main()
{
  int a=1, b=2, ab[]={10,20};
  printf( "%d", ab[a] );
  printf( "%d", a );
  printf( "%d", a );
}
```

Now, replace variables with their actual values, i.e. `ab[a]` with `20` and `a` with `1`

```
main()
{
  int a=1, b=2, ab[]={10,20};
  printf( "%d", 20 );
  printf( "%d", 1 );
  printf( "%d", 1 );
}
```

Comment: impressive analysis

Comment: Wow, this opens up a whole new world of possibilities. :D Thank you!

Comment: @Eutherpy: No.  No it doesn't.  Pretend you've never seen that.

Comment: @Eutherpy Digraphs and trigraphs were some really bad ideas that were added to the standard to support various exotic computer keyboard layouts all over the world (instead of coming up with a keyword standard). They are a thing of the past, nowadays they are regarded as 100% bad practice.

Comment: these days they should add similar support for emoji 